# Lexus gs300 no throttle response

Tags: cel, lexus, throttle-body, throttle-position-sensor

I have a 2005 Lexus gs300. Today while driving the car, it started to drop rpms while in drive.. as I drove further I was not able to get a response from pressing the gas pedal. The car can roll on it's own power nothing else. When I got home I checked the codes and I got a couple codes: P2121, P2127, P2138, P2757. What do I do now should I replace the whole throttlebody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the results found when searching online for the error codes, it appears that the main issue you're seeing is caused by the throttle pedal sensor, and isn't related to the throttle body.

> P2121 - Throttle/Pedal Position Sensor/Switch 'D' Circuit Range/Performance.
>   P2127 - Throttle Position Sensor E Circuit Low Input.
>   P2138 - Throttle/Pedal Position Sensor/Switch D/E Voltage Correlation.
>   P2757 - Torque Converter Clutch Press Control Solenoid Control Circuit Performance or Stuck Off.

I'd recommend checking the connection to the sensor to make sure it's securely plugged in and not corroded.

The last code P2757 looks somewhat different though. I don't know how they relate to each other, but one switch being stuck might trigger decreased voltage somewhere else, so checking all the sensors/switches would be good.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Where is the  pedal position  sensor located some places I looked say it's on or near the pedal and other places say it's near the throttlebody. And there is 2 different sensors that were manufactured.

Answer (score 0):

have the same issue in my 2000 GS300. Already cleaned and checked connectors and replaced TPS sensor then noticed i dont hear the throttle motor moving when i move the throttle linkage with the key on. Have a spare motor gonna swap out the entire throttle body unit.